# Open DatePicker from a Popup window

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to open a DatePicker from a popup. When I click the datepicker, the date input page (the one with spinners) opens behind the Popup.

How can the DatePicker go over the popup window and return to it after I select the date?

This is how I open the popup:

```
private void btnShowBuyNow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup buyNowScreen;
        buyNowScreen = new Popup();
        buyNowScreen.Child = 
            new BuyNowScreen
                ("Buy this application and get rid of the ads!");
        buyNowScreen.IsOpen = true;
        buyNowScreen.VerticalOffset = 100;
        buyNowScreen.HorizontalOffset = 25;
        buyNowScreen.Closed += (s1, e1) =>
            {
                // Add you code here to do something 
                // when the Popup is closed
            };
    }
```

DatePicker in the popup's xaml file:

```
<toolbox:DatePicker x:Name="DatePick" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Events:

Add a button in your PopUp with the DatePicker. When the button is clicked have an event to close the PopUp

### XAML

```
<toolbox:DatePicker x:Name="DatePick" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" IsEnabled="True"/>
<Button Click="DateAcceptedClick"/>
```

### CodeBehind for Popup

```
public event DateAcceptedButtonClick DateAcceptedButtonEvent;
public delegate void DateAcceptedButtonClick (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);

private void DateAcceptedClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (DateAcceptedButtonEvent!= null)
         DateAcceptedButtonEvent(sender, e);
}
```

### CodeBehind for Popup Parent

```
Popup BuyNowScreen;
private void btnShowBuyNow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BuyNowScreen = new Popup();
    BuyNowScreen.Child = new BuyNowScreen("Buy this application and get rid of the ads!");
    BuyNowScreen.IsOpen = true;
    BuyNowScreen.VerticalOffset = 100;
    BuyNowScreen.HorizontalOffset = 25;
    BuyNowScreen.DateAcceptedButtonEvent += new DateAcceptedButtonClick(PopupDateAcceptedButtonClick)
}

private void PopupDateAcceptedButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BuyNowScreen.IsOpen = false;
    //Closed logic
}
```